# Snort DAQ: which NIC should run in promiscuous mode?

Tags: linux, snort, ips

I want to use Snort 2.x as IPS. I have understood, that I need two NICs to capture the traffic (DAQ-Mode).

- `eth0` = my network card to the WAN
- `eth1` = my internal (virtual) NIC for Snort.

My current Run-Command:

```
snort -u snort -g snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf --daq afpacket -i eth0:eth1 -l /var/log/snort -Q
```

How I enable the PROMISC-Mode:

```
tee /etc/rc.local <<EOF
#!/bin/sh -e
ifconfig eth0 promisc
ifconfig eth1 promisc
exit 0
EOF
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
systemctl start rc-local
```

Which of the two card do i need to put in promiscuous mode? `eth0`, `eth1` or even both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what traffic you want to capture. If you want all of the traffic that `eth0` and `eth1` see, then use `-i eth0:eth1`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.